# Question has multiple upvotes and answers, but none of the answers have upvotes

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727283/simplify-a-complex-regular-expression) is an example of what I mean, although I don't mean to complain about that particular question but questions like this in general. This question has 6 answers and (*coincidentally..?*) 6 upvotes. All 6 answers have *no* votes at all, nor is there an accepted answer. This does not seem ideal at all for a Q&A site; the impression is that the question is unsolved and that the answers are poor. In fact most of the answers solve the asker's problem and they seem to be of roughly equal quality.

How should one deal with such a question? Should more answers be provided or existing answers revised to get the question out of stasis? Could something be changed to make such situations less likely to happen?

To me it seems that although the question got enough attention, it became "stuck" because of the answerers' egos; they don't want to vote for competing answers out of jealousy or spite.

So, as an answerer in such a question, should I upvote competing answers even though they were later and not *particularly* better than mine?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why would you upvote answers if you think they're not good ?

Comment: I think the only real issue here is the asker not going through the answers and selecting one.

Comment: @dystroy: No, to get the question towards something that looks like a 'solved' state, where at least one answer floats to the top being recognized as a good answer, accepted by the asker or not. Currently, any visitor (from Google or from similar questions) might think that this was not answered conclusively and start a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing needs to be done.

We are all here [embracing the suck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/05/how-to-stop-sucking-and-be-awesome-instead.html) and learning to suck less together.  (Gosh I sound like an SO party man.  Forgive me.)

You (and other answerers) didn't get any reputation this time, but you and one other person did get some discussion in the comments on your answer.

So, you suck less for having answered this question.

Congratulations!  You've won!

Answer (score 3):

Upvote the good answers. Downvote the awful answers. Ignore the "meh" answers. If you feel so inclined, provide your own answer.

And then move on.

Comment: The problem is when you've already answered. You can't upvote your own answer, and if someone else's is better you wouldn't have written your own.

Comment: @Mark: Not necessarily. There are often multiple ways to tackle a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Those unended questions are usually asked by users with exactly 1 reputation point.

I sometimes leave a comment asking for an accept but I guess there is no solution to force a user come back to SO once he got his answer. Upvoting competing answers wouldn't change anything.

I'm just now reluctant to answer users with only one point, especially if the question seems easy and not really interesting (so not fun).